# javascript object constructor with objects

Tags: javascript

I understand this is object constructor function. Simple to understand for beginner.

```
var myFather = new Person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
```

What about this?
inside new keyword there are objects.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  message: 'Hello Vue!'
 }
})
```

This one has .Store. How does it work?

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    increment (state) {
      state.count++
    }
  }
})
```

Please let me know if there are any websites I can read. Thanks.

Comment: 2nd one just accepts an object in the constructor, eg `function Vue(options) { ... }`. 3rd one is just namespaced, eg `const Vuex = { Store: function(options) { ... } }`

Comment: It seems to me you need to read up on function parameters. When you type for instance `new Vue()` you are essentially just calling the function `Vue()`, but storing an instance of the resulting object that IS the function (because in JavaScript a function is also technically an object).

Answer (score 0):

They are simply passing an object literal to the constructor.

the same as doing this:

```
let obj = {
   el: '#app',
   data: {
     message: 'Hello Vue!'
   }
}

let app = new Vue(obj);
```

As for your Vuex.Store - there is simply a Store constructor function attatched on to the prototype of the Vuex constructor function. In other words a static method - which is a constructor has been added.

Theoretical Vuex Constructor:

Old style syntax:

```
 function Vuex(...){
     ....
 }

 Vuex.prototype.Store = function(object){
     this.object = object; // could be this but doesnt have to be
     this.something = object.x;
     this.somethingElse = object.y;
     ...
 }
```

ES6 class syntax:

```
class Vuex {
  constructor(){...};
  ...
}

Vuex.Store = class {
  constructor(object){
      this.object = object; // could be this but doesnt have to be
      this.something = object.x;
      this.somethingElse = object.y;
      // deal with object ...

  }

}
```

All be it this is my limited understanding...

Comment: Setting `Vuex.prototype.Store = function(){}` won't make `Vuex.Store()` work. You are setting it on the `prototype` which is (as strange as it sounds) not in the prototype chain for `Vuex` it *will* be in the chain for instances of `Vuex`